# Planning unit tests with TDD

Tags: tdd

When you approach a class you want to write, how do you plan its unit tests?
Are there formal templates which you follow or do you use pen and paper/notepad?
I am looking for some way to let other programmers/QAs know what tests should be implemented (and if something was overlooked it can be easier to spot it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), tests drive the feature you are writing.  If you're needing to write formal templates for it, then chances are you're not entering into the spirit of things!

TDD should be used to generate the test cases as you write the code.  Simply put, before you write the next line of code, encode in a test what the code should do.

Check out Bob Martin's [bowling game](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/xpepisode.htm) example which should give you more of a feel for TDD.

Comment: I would also add that if you're doing TDD and want to make a note of tests you know you still need to write, I use index cards and a pencil. Others I know write the test methods and mark them as ignored.

Comment: @bcarlso: That exactly what I'm looking for. A way to track what tests are already implemented and what tests aren't.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that having a template goes well with using TDD. I assume that you have read Kent Beck's Book on Test Driven Development by Example. If no please do so.

But the general idea is simple. When we start a class, we will have a general idea on the responsibility of the class. This is the steps that we use:

1. Have a general idea on class
   responsibility and use that
   information to name the class.
2. Create a test case for this class.
3. If you start with a concrete information on what the units inside the class are, just write those stubs inside the class and write test cases for those stubs. Initially all of it will fail and the signatures for most of those methods will change. That's the whole idea.
4. In most cases, the developer may not have that degree of information.  In that case, it's OK to start writing code in the First Test. Once the test passes, then migrate the logic to the class.

So what I am driving at is, the whole point of TDD is to make the development process more organic. The class grows, with the knowledge on what it should do. Having a formal template, or writing things down, will probably not help.

The only thing I could think that you could do, is to sit  with your developers before each iteration and come up with a pretty detailed idea on each of the component classes and its responsibilities (we only use this discussion to finalize public APIs).

If you want to know the quality of test cases written by your developer, then you can conduct an ad hoc code review to see if the classes are correctly broken down to units and all the units are tested.

Comment: I am talking here about something that looks more or less like a checklist. Say method DoFoo can throw both ArgumentNullException and InvalidOperationException. Somehow I have to be sure that I've written all the failure tests (is that the right term?) I need. I'm talking about a document which specifies expected results of a certain method. This document can provide both a reference and a way to communicate what is tested already (or should be tested and was forgotten). Does that really validate TDD?

Comment: What you are looking at is, tooling support. There are some fairly sophisticated Test Coverage Analysis tools, that provides statistics on the portion of the code that is not covered by testing. If the method is written with correct pre-condition and post condition then the tool should help gauge the quality of the tests written.

Comment: So you are saying that it's not worth thinking of all of the tests that should be written ahead of time? I already know the interface of the class. Isn't it worth making sure all tests are written?

Comment: @thedrow, each case is slightly different. I do not completely know, the dynamics of your situation. According to me, there is no need to have a documentation or thinking time. Once all the components are laid out , the developer needs to test all possible program flows. There is tooling support to gauge how well Unit Testing is applied. If I see cases where the testing is bad, then ( there is a particular developer in my company who is horrible...) you need to let him know and train him.

Answer (score 1):

TDD is not the methodology you are looking for ;-)

```
way to let other programmers/QAs know what tests should be implemented
```

This statement implies you are after tests, but TDD itself is driven by requirements and produces features - the fact that it also produces a suite of tests is an incidental (but hugely powerful) appendage which happens to result in a regression suite.

Although TDD harnesses 'tests' to drive development of code, you do not need to specify tests up-front.  Even if you did (and sometimes is helpful to 'thinking' to do so) your programmer may not need to write all the tests in order to produce the desired behaviour in the code.  Indeed, in TDD, you are encouraged to stop work when all the tests pass - you need not keep on writing tests only to find they already pass; that is something akin to makework.

Also, the other side-effect of TDD is in having (and continuously running) a regression suite.  If at a later date a bug is found, it makes it easier, just by having a test suite, to write *another* test which demonstrates the bug with a failing test.  Once the bug is fixed, the test should pass - along with *all* the other tests in the suite.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot commit to TDD and let others do the unit testing. This requirement of yours strongly suggest that You haven't understood the TDD paradigm.

In my (admittedly fairly new) experience

- You write test that, if passed, will confirm your initial understanding of the target funcitonality. Not a single line of production code is written at this point.
- You then Implement the production code so the unit tests are passed.
- If your understanding evolves, you then change your unit tests or/and add new ones
- You then implement the changes in the production code so the tests will pass
- By then, it is not forbidden to write additional unit tests, if you discover that parts of your production code are not covered.
- Remove tests that no longer make sense.
- You arrive at beautiful crisp and clean code :o)

TDD is NOT a QA method; It is a way of DEVELOPING. The whole idea is that the unit test guide the development process. So you really can't let others do the unit tests for you.

Answer (score 0):

I start by designing the class first, usually with a simple UML class diagram. I try not to make the diagram just detailed enough so that I can run tests against it (e.g. params and return types specified for each method, and I know how the method's behavior affects object state).

Then, I write unit tests. Generally when it comes to automated testing you should have 1 test method for every method defined in your class. As far as convention goes, if I have a method in my class called `myMethod`, then my unit test method will be called `testMyMethod`.

I write unit tests using what I know about the method's intended behavior, and then write the method and check to make sure that it passes the unit test.

Comment: testMyMethod is kinda a bad name. There are tools that when given a formatted test name can produce a nice report. For a test named VerifyThat_WhenDoingFoo_NoExceptionIsThrown there are report tools which can split the name into Action: When Doing Foo. Expected Result: No Exception Is Thrown. Test Result: Passed.

Comment: @the_drow the method names were purely for illustrative purposes. Most unit test frameworks are capable of auto-generating test methods based upon class methods, anyway.